# Split string from text file in human-friendly format

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

How to split some strings from a txt file defined in a specific format:

```
[length relevant char number]name=value[length relevant char number]name=value[length relevant char number]name=value[length relevant char number]name=value
```

Is possible to read a file containing these information an to split it in a new file (as decribed below) with a simple Python script?

---

Eg.

INPUT:

```
0010name=mario0013surname=rossi0006age=180006phone=0014address=street
0013name=marianna0013surname=rossi0006age=210006phone=0015address=street1
0003name=pia0015surname=rossini0005age=30017phone=+39221122330020address=streetstreet
```

OUTPUT:

```
name=mario surname=rossi age=18 phone= address=street
name=marianna surname=rossi age=21 phone= address=street1
name=pia surname=rossini age=3 phone=+3922112233 address=streetstreet
```

Comment: What do you mean by "length relevant char number"?

Comment: I notice that this is the third time you've asked how to solve exactly the same problem in three different languages/tools. There's nothing inherently wrong with this, but have you tried reapplying their solutions in Python instead of starting from scratch?

If this isn't a one-off problem, but your job or education or hobby, it would probably benefit you more in the long run if you tried to reuse either the iterative solution or the regex solution and asked how to overcome the differences between your languages/tools instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to identify the pattern (which I am assuming is 4 numerals followed by a lowercase letter) and then replace the (part of) the pattern with `str.replace`

```py
s = '0010name=mario0013surname=rossi0006age=180006phone=0014address=street'
for pat in re.findall(r'(\d{4})[a-z]', s):
    s = s.replace(pat, ' ')

print(s.strip())
# name=mario surname=rossi age=18 phone= address=street
```

Comment: This assumes that no key starts with a digit, which isn't guaranteed by the short format specification we get.

Comment: True. Not just digits. Uppercase, non-ascii will also trip this up